# Expo build fail: Repeated error about transparency on icon in expo build despite no transparency

Tags: ios, build, expo

I have been trying all afternoon to run expo build:ios with expo-cli for the first time so I can get my first expo app onto TestFlight but I'm repeatedly getting the error: "Your application icon can't have transparency if you wish to upload your app to Apple Store."

I have checked with get info and the icon file is showing no alpha channel.  I've put the icon on a white background and merged the layers in photoshop which is supposed to remove transparency, I've even tried saving it as a jpeg so there isn't transparency but the result is the same.  I've checked my app.json file and it's in line with the example given in a similar issue on the expo github channel.  It's also here: https://github.com/callyb/expo-cli-build-error/blob/master/app.json.

I am at a loss - the app works great on both my devices and simulators, published on expo and running in expo production mode and I just can't see where the error might be (I'm assuming it's probably not the icon...)  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Are there any tools I can use to check where the error may be?  Many thanks for any help...

Comment: Yup, too little sleep and too much coding!  It was the predictable - the path to the icon in app.json did not match the actual path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for answering Ahmed Anwar, but I had already saved it without an alpha channel as I stated...in fact I found the answer a while ago, which was as I put accidentally in the comments instead of answering my own question!  So the answer was:

Yup, too little sleep and too much coding! It was the predictable - the path to the icon in app.json did not match the actual path...

Sometimes it's just too obvious!! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I used this website:

https://www.online-image-editor.com/

Upload image -> Advanced settings -> Transparency -> Remove transparency -> Save

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue, i had png which was using aplha.

To resolve the issue, open your png image and save it without aplha setting.

Here is the github reference for checking alpha in PGN.
[don't allow to use png icon with alpha channel](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/commit/f13b545b9f5626ffc91502a7ae1d5f0937c723ca)

If you are on a macbook, just preview your icon and export it by unchecking Alpha property.

[image: Export form Preview]

Comment: Worked wonders!